# How long does Legendary Defender of Ascalon take these days?

Tags: guild-wars

I'm a bit of a Guild Wars noob, but I've always been interested in going for the Legendary Defender of Ascalon title.  I've started up a character in Pre-Searing, and I've been working my way up to level 10 (using the tips posted [on the official Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Legendary_Defender_Of_Ascalon) for guidance).

With Lieutenant Langmar's quests now available for level 10 and higher characters, and the ability to farm those repeatedly for XP, does anyone have a sort of ballpark idea on how long it takes you to get the title these days?  I can spend up to an hour a day working on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most things in Guild Wars, it depends on whether that hour a day you can spend can be extended at all. The fastest current way found is to repeatedly farm the first few enemies on the Farmer Hamnet quest, detailed here - claimed LDoA in 2-3 days:

http://www.guildwarsguru.com/forum/fastest-way-ldoa-t10473064.html?t=10473064&highlight=ldoa+speed

Other than that, if we discount the exp you'll gain from killing foes for the sake of simplicity, you'll need 101,000 experience to get from level 10 to level 20, and at 1,000 experience per day, you're looking at about 101 days, probably quite a few less since you'll be killing some monsters to gain exp along the way. Cut that number down further if you have some time to go Charr hunting in the Northlands; it's a great way to get up to 14 or so in a few days without being as boring as farming one mob over and over again. At an hour a day, plan on devoting 2-3 months at it, and you'll probably be pleasantly surprised.

Almost forgot to mention, class matters a bit more in pre as well. If you're, say, a Ranger, you might be able to take advantage of the bonus weapons that come with pre-ordering some of the games if you did that, or owning collector's editions. AoE scatter also doesn't exist in pre, so quite a few people like running Elementalists or Ele secondaries for that reason.

Comment: I stopped trying for this at level 16 (14k+ deaths), maybe now I'll finish up the last 4 levels.

Comment: Wanted to say thank you, I got my LDOA title a week or so ago, mostly due to your advice and the advice in your link.  Thanks again!